# Facebook API "Method in protocol not implemented"

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I did in my `AppDelegate`:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
Facebook *facebook;
}
```

And followed the tutorial on Facebook Developers, but it is still doing four-times like:

1. Method declared here (`Facebook.h`):

   - `(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled;`
2. Required for direct or indirect protocol `FBSessionDelegate` (`AppDelegate.h`):

   ```
   @interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, FBSessionDelegate> {
   Facebook *facebook;
   }
   ```

Is there something I forgot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your AppDelegate states to follow the FBSessionDelegate protocol, it needs to implement all required methods from this protocol.

So you need to implemented the fbDidNotLogin method in your AppDelegate.m like

```
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
    // Do something here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Hackbook example, you have to add some more methods :

```
- (void)storeAuthData:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:accessToken forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:expiresAt forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];}

    -(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled{
    }

    -(void)fbDidExtendToken:(NSString *)accessToken expiresAt:(NSDate *)expiresAt{

    NSLog(@"token extended");
    [self storeAuthData:accessToken expiresAt:expiresAt];
}

- (void)fbSessionInvalidated {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                              initWithTitle:@"Auth Exception"
                              message:@"Your session has expired."
                              delegate:nil
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil,
                              nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [self fbDidLogout];
}
```